# MySQL query from an array with limit and order by

Tags: mysql, arrays, sorting, limit

I am not a professional programmer, but I assist a school in automating their assessments. I have a list of just over 1000 students with 3 assessment scores for each one every year and I need to create a list with the average of these three scores in descending order, limiting it to the top 30. I can calculate averages and display the results, but I can't sort or limit. In the first part of the code, I select the IDs from all students and store them into the array *$alunos[]* for the current year *($IDanoatual)*. In the second part, I use a for loop to calculate the average of these grades for each student and display them. Both codes lookup the same table *( audp_l_notasfinais)*. I tried using the foreach statement to filter and sort, but I couldn't resolve this issue.

```
            $sela = "select id_aluno from audp_l_notasfinais
            where id_ano = '$IDanoatual'
            ";
            $qsela = mysqli_query($conn,$sela);
            $contasel = mysqli_num_rows($qsela);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qsela)){
                $alunos[] = $row['id_aluno'];
            }

            for ($i=0; $i<$contasel; $i++){
            $selnotasA = "select avg(NULLIF(nts.mef,0)) as NtutA, aln.stdname Naln
            from audp_l_notasfinais nts
            inner join audp_c_alunos aln on aln.id_alunos = nts.id_aluno
            where nts.id_aluno = '$alunos[$i]' and nts.id_ano='$IDanoatual'
            ";
            $qrynmal = mysqli_query($conn,$selnotasA);

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrynmal)){
             echo "Name: ".$row['Naln']." -  Average: ".$row['NtutA']."<br>";    
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not included much detail in your question. Adding your `CREATE TABLE` statements and some sample data in markdown tables would help, and get a better response.

It looks like `$IDanoatual` could be coming from user input, in which case you really need to read about and understand [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and how to mitigate the risk with [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Best guess -

```
select aln.id_alunos, aln.stdname Naln, avg(NULLIF(nts.mef,0)) as NtutA
from audp_c_alunos aln
inner join audp_l_notasfinais nts
    on aln.id_alunos = nts.id_aluno
    and nts.id_ano = '$IDanoatual'
group by aln.id_alunos
order by NtutA desc
limit 30;
```